# How do I dynamically change response with Mockswitch?

Tags: mockswitch

I am recently exploring [Mockswitch](https://mockswitch.com) mocking services and wondering if it's possible to change the response type dynamically with Mockswitch per request? I see there is a dynamic response type but I assume it's for faker.

[image: Mockswitch app service update]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change responses based request matching. In each "response case" you build you can add request matching rule which would match requests based on headers, query, body params.

Documentation here: [Mock services Request matching](https://mockswitch.com/docs/#matching)

[image: Service request matching]